# Train SVM with OpenCV using colour histograms

Tags: python, c++, opencv, image-processing, svm

I'm very new to OpenCV, and i want to create simple object detector, that uses SVM. Instead of HOG, i would like to extract from my object color histograms(for example), but i couldn't find any information about it for OpenCV, everywhere is using HOG.

And my second question: is Python implemenation for SVM has less functionality than C++ (both for OpenCV) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the OpenCV function `calcHist` to compute histograms.

```
calcHist(&bgr_planes[0], 1, 0, Mat(), b_hist, 1, &histSize, &histRange, uniform, accumulate );
```

where,

- &bgr_planes[0]: The source array(s)
- 1: The number of source arrays
- 0: The channel (dim) to be measured. In this case it is just the
  intensity so we just write 0.
- Mat(): A mask to be used on the source array
- b_hist: The Mat object where the histogram will be stored
- 1: The histogram dimensionality.
- histSize: The number of bins per each used dimension
- histRange: The range of values to be measured per each dimension
  uniform and accumulate

Refer to the [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_calculation/histogram_calculation.html) for more information.

You can also look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694810/using-opencv-and-svm-with-images) which discusses C++ OpenCV SVM implementation and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8687885/python-opencv-svm-implementation?rq=1) which discusses Python OpenCV SVM implementation to get started.

Comment: Thanks for an answer! And in &bgr_planes i should put all my positive and negative images? And after that i must teach SVM on histograms, that i will get with this function?